# Unexpected behavior with boostrap when resizing viewport

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

**Steps to Replicate**
1. Expand browser window to full screen (performed on a notebook).
2. Keep resizing window.

**Expected Behavior:** 
Resizing browser window resizes the DIV elements.

**Actual Behavior:** 
DIV elements do not appear to be fully resizing as shown by the background color being displayed (orange).

**References:** 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X89o.png)
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/starno/66ar5pkf/)

**External Resources:**
bootstrap.min.js
bootstrap.min.css
bootstrap-theme.min.css
jquery-2.2.4.min.js

**HTML**

```
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid" id="top">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" id="intro-row">
        <h2 id="intro-content">Lorem ipsum Dolore sunt cillum laboris in veniam.</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-row">
      <a href="#top">Lorem ipsum Laboris ex Duis cillum incididunt aliqua.</a>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: orange;
}

#header-row {
    background-color: green;
}
.header-content {
    margin: 30px 30px 30px 15px;
    font-size: 2em;
}

#intro-row {
    background-color: blue;
}
#intro-content {
    margin: 100px 150px 100px 150px;
    font-size: 12em;
    text-align: left;
}

.footer-row {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your `#intro-row` following css:

```
#intro-row {
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It seems bootstrap is removing the float left attribute which makes it work if the viewport is more than 992px.

---

### EDIT

Alternatively you can give your intro-row ID following bootstrap classes in your HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="intro-row">
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix this is to change the margins in your `#intro-content` and instead use padding for the top and bottom of the text.

```
#intro-content {
    margin: 0 150px 0 150px;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: left;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ian_A/u1tacmmL/)

**EDIT:** Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```
/* Remove this: */
#intro-row {
    background-color: blue;
}

/* Add this: */
#top > .row {
    background-color: blue;
}
```